# Specify arc color by origin node arcplot {arcdiagram}

Tags: r, igraph, arc-diagram

I have an arcplot with node order manually specified. I had hoped to set arc color by manually specifying with a list as well. However, the colors don't line up to the nodes:

Where red, blue, and green were previously defined as:

```
red <- "firebrick1"
green <- "green3"
blue <- "DodgerBlue"

color.names <- setNames(c(red, red, red, red, red,red,red,red,red,red,red,red, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue,  blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, blue,green, green , green, green ), c("OVB", "OVB-ENV", "OVB-ENV-MO", "OVB-MO", "OVB-MO-ENV", "ENV-MO", "ENV", "ENV-OVB", "ENV-MO-OVB", "MO","MO-ENV","MO-OVB", "intraverbal-tact", "intraverbal", "intraverbal-mand", "intraverbal-tact-mand","intraverbal-mand-tact", "intraverbal-echoic-mand", "intraverbal-echoic", "tact", "tact-mand", "tact-intraverbal", "tact-intraverbal-mand", "mand", "mand-tact", "mand-intraverbal", "mand-tact-intraverbal","echoic-tact", "echoic-intraverbal-mand", "echoic-intraverbal", "echoic-tact-mand","echoic-intraverbal-tact", "echoic-mand","echoic-mand-intraverbal", "echoic-tact-intraverbal","social", "social-physical", "physical-social", "physical"))

longer_order = c("OVB", "OVB-ENV", "OVB-ENV-MO", "OVB-MO", "OVB-MO-ENV", "ENV-MO", "ENV", "ENV-OVB", "ENV-MO-OVB", "MO","MO-ENV","MO-OVB", "intraverbal-tact", "intraverbal", "intraverbal-mand", "intraverbal-tact-mand","intraverbal-mand-tact", "intraverbal-echoic-mand", "intraverbal-echoic", "tact", "tact-mand", "tact-intraverbal", "tact-intraverbal-mand", "mand", "mand-tact", "mand-intraverbal", "mand-tact-intraverbal","echoic-tact", "echoic-intraverbal-mand", "echoic-intraverbal", "echoic-tact-mand","echoic-intraverbal-tact", "echoic-mand","echoic-mand-intraverbal", "echoic-tact-intraverbal","social", "social-physical", "physical-social", "physical"))
```

There are 738 edges.

To graph the plot:

```
library(arcdiagram)
arcplot(F1, ordering=longer_order, col.arcs = color.names)
```

Is there something akin to igraph's get.edglist() for arcplot's (unique) list of nodes to graph (from an edge-list)? 
Some other way to programmatically add the colors of the edges by origin?

To reproduce the data:

```
F1 <- structure(c("OVB", "OVB", "OVB", "OVB", "OVB-ENV", "OVB", "OVB","intraverbal-mand", "intraverbal-mand", "mand", "intraverbal","mand", "intraverbal-tact", "intraverbal", "mand-intraverbal","intraverbal-mand", "mand", "physical-social", "physical-social","social-physical"), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL,c("V1", "V2")))
```

Comment: Are colours not supposed to be in quotes: `setNames(c("red", "red", ...` instead of `setNames(c(red, red` ? Also `col.names` is supposed to be `color.names`?

Comment: Personal opinion, I stopped using arcplots because of sankey from googleVis package, see if it works for you.

Comment: 1. as mentioned above, the color variables red, etc. had been previously defined, i.e., red not "red"
2. Sankey diagrams with googleVis look awesome. I'll need to give them a try.

Comment: They've been added above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
longer_order_match  <- order(match(unique(matrix(F1)), longer_order))
color.names_match <- color.names[match(unique(matrix(F1)), longer_order)]

arcplot(F1, ordering = longer_order_match, col.arcs = color.names_match)
```

We need to provide same number of elements as number of edges to `ordering =` and `col.arcs =` arguments. So we are subsetting your predefined orders and columns vectors using `match()`.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the structure command didn't faithfully reproduce the order.